# Combining parts to a single stl for cheaper printing

Tags: objects, import

I am trying to compine parts for 3 raspberry pi cases so I can print them as a single image and avoid paying a setup fee for every single one 
I have stl files 
When I import them to blender they float around in different sizes and locations 
I'm just trying to get them all to fit on a 12 by 12 inch floor and have no clue how to do it 
Googling didn't help much since I am a total newbie and don't even understand some of the jargon

If anyone can hep I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful (and often confusing) world of Blender!

So, the first thing you'll need to do is right-click the default cube to select it.*

- Hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> to scale the cube up by 6. Hit <kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd> to finish. (You'll see Dimensions in the right panel go to 12 in each direction. We're pretending the units are inches.)
- Set the cube's maximum draw type to Wire, this will avoid it getting in the way:

[image: maxdrawtype]

Ignore the cube for now.

- Now, do you have a number pad? If not, you should probably go into the preferences (⌘, on a mac, <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> elsewhere) and turn on Emulate Numpad in the Input tab. Be sure to hit the Save User Settings button, or you'll get a surprise when you restart Blender!
- Hit <kbd>1</kbd> on the numpad, or the regular key if you've got Emulate Numpad turned on. This will align your view so you're looking straight on sideways. Then hit <kbd>5</kbd> on the numpad to switch to "orthographic mode"; this makes your view flat, like an architectural drawing. (There is no perspective; things that are far away look just as big as things that are up close.)
- Turn on snapping with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. If it gives you trouble later, you can turn it off again.
- For each case (I'm assuming they're all one piece here, please tell me if not):

  - Select it by right-clicking.
  - Hit <kbd>G</kbd> to Grab it, and then <kbd>Z</kbd> to only move it along the Z axis (up/down).
  - Move your mouse up/down until the bottom of the case is aligned with the floor, which is that red horizontal line going across your viewport.

---

Now you need that cube again.

- Select it by right-clicking on its wire.
- Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and move it up 6 to align it with the floor.
- Hit <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to switch to top view.
- Grab each case, like before except without the Z locking, and make sure it's inside the cube's walls.
- If you want them to all be one piece, join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
- Delete the default cube with <kbd>X</kbd>. Now you're done! You can find STL export under the File menu.

---

Please note that I used <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to mean "press B while holding A", and <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to mean "press A, then B".

---

<sub>*Yes, it's weird, but you get used to it. If you absolutely hate it, you can change it in the preferences. Just make sure to hit "save user settings" afterward.</sub>

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply I appreciate it I am trying to do that but the problem is that the files I am importing are so much bigger than the cube and I don't know what their dimentions should be (I assume the stl.is supposed to contain that information)like so can't scale them down and they don't fit in the cube. Each case is made of a few independent part but each stl file contains a single  part so no connections are necessary Ican send you the files if you want to see them my email is bialostozky2822   At gmail if you'd like send me an email and I'll send you the files

Comment: So, you can't scale them down? Is it because they're made of separate parts?

Comment: Also, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)), STL doesn't contain scale information. Blender's units are arbitrary, so you can pretend they're anything you like. (BTW, some things like rendering engines often assume they're in meters, but since you're not using rendering, that doesn't matter.)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering I appreciate your time   I can scale down but I need them to fit the raspberry pi zero so I don't know to what size to scale them down since I don't have the dimensions they're supposed to be I assumed when I downloaded them from thingiverse that they're in a specific size and yes some cases are made of 2 parts or more

Comment: Well, does the page where you got them say anything about dimensions? If so, you could use that to figure out how big they need to be. If not, you could try finding the dimensions online. Also, if you want to print the pieces (of one case) separately, you can just use the same scale on all of them and align them with the floor independently.